# Midrashic non-literalism in the Taz

Tags: midrash, literalism

The [Taz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal) writes in his Divrei David (Genesis 1:23) regarding a Midrash:

> ואין לנו להפקיע דברי חכמים מפשטן

"We should not remove words of the Sages from their simple interpretations."

Does the Taz ever interpret a Midrash non-literally?